# Any idea why function worked for one, but not the other?

Tags: python

I am working on trying to cluster a couple of text documents. I can't seem to figure out why this worked for question 1, but not for question two.

```
path = '/Users/shelina/Desktop/Web_/_Data/'
filePrefix = 'Week1_Q'
dataset={}
dataset_raw = {}
questions=[1,2,3,4]


for question in questions:
    fileName=path+filePrefix+str(question)+".txt"
    f=open(fileName,'r')
    text = ''
    text_raw = ''    
    lines=f.readlines()
    tot_articles+=len(lines)
    articles_count[str(question)] = len(lines)
    dataset_raw[str(question)] = list(map(lambda line: line.lower(), lines))

for question in questions:
    print("Processing: " +str(question))
    clean_stuff= []
    tokenized_stuff = []
    index = 1
    for stuff in dataset_raw[str(question)]:
        index+=1
        tokens = apply_stopwording(remove_punctuation(nltk.Text(nltk.word_tokenize(str(dataset_raw[str(question)])))), 3)
    clean_text = apply_lemmatization(tokens)
    clean_stuff.append(clean_text)
    tokenized_stuff.append(tokens)
    lemmas_list=[]
    token_list=[]

    lemmas_list.extend(l for lemma in clean_stuff for l in lemma)
    token_list.extend(t for token in tokenized_stuff for t in token)

    token_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame({'terms': token_list}, index = lemmas_list)

    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

    terms=[str(set(token)) for token in clean_stuff]

    #define vectorizer parameters
    tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', use_idf=True)
    tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(terms)

    print(tfidf_matrix.shape)

    features = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()

    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    k = 10
    k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
    k_means.fit(tfidf_matrix)
    clusters = k_means.labels_.tolist()
    idk_space = {'term':terms, 'cluster':clusters}
    kmean_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(idk_space,index=[clusters], columns =['term','cluster'])
    kmean_dataframe['cluster'].value_counts()
    n=10

    print('Top %s terms within clusters' % n)
    print()

    sorted_centroids = k_means.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]

    for cluster_number in range(k):
        token_string = ''

    for ind in sorted_centroids[cluster_number, :n]:
        token_string = token_string +  token_dataframe.ix[features[ind].split(' ')].values.tolist()[0][0] + ', '

    print("Cluster %d: %s" % (cluster_number, token_string))
```

Output:

```
Processing: Question 2
(27, 547)
Top 10 terms within clusters

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)  
<ipython-input-35-17d8b3801710> in <module>()
 49   
 50     for ind in sorted_centroids[cluster_number, :n]:
---> 51         token_string = token_string + token_dataframe.ix[features[ind].split(' ')].values.tolist()[0][0] + ', '
     52 
     53     print("Cluster %d: %s" % (cluster_number, token_string))

TypeError: must be str, not float
```

Why did this work for question number one, but then gives me an error with question number two. How can I fix this issue? I'm a little confused.

Thanks.

Comment: The error doesn't come from the code you show... [mcve] please

Answer (score 0):

You're using `ix`. From pandas docs:

> .ix supports mixed integer and label based access. It is primarily label based, but will fall back to integer positional access unless the corresponding axis is of integer type. .ix is the most general and will support any of the inputs in .loc and .iloc. .ix also supports floating point label schemes. .ix is exceptionally useful when dealing with mixed positional and label based hierachical indexes.

You should observe your rows and see that when you're accessing using `ix`, you're getting mixed types out of it.

Without more elaboration on what the data actually is, this is likely the issue for your problem.

A potential fix is to replace `ix` with `loc` or `iloc`, which does not support positional access.